# How to update Jar/dependent project in an Eclipse Tomcat project?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin

I have a Tomcat project (sysdeo tomcat plugin) that is dependent on a another project's jar.

I want to update the jar/project so I removed the jar from the library and added the other project as dependent under the Java Build Path -> Projects.  I refreshed, closed/open the project, restarted Eclipse, clean and rebuilt all projects in the Eclipse (Java EE - Juno), yet the changes to the other project are not picked up by Eclipse.

When I debug and step in it goes to the right source, but the errors indicate that it is still referencing the old jar.

I've removed jar from Java Build Path -> Library in all projects under the workspace, and have attached the project, in case it is looking at the wrong Jar.

I have read through other similar questions, but non of the suggestions have worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Eclipse builds the WAR file, which will be deployed on the Tomcat server, it could be the reason, that Eclipse doesn't export the other project to JAR automatically.

You have to export the other project manually by

> Right-Click on project name / Export / Java / JAR file

and copy the generated JAR file to (in my case):

> [Tomcat project]/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/

The sources that folder contains will be included in the WAR file.

Hope it helps :-)

Comment: I tried your suggestion.  I am getting "resource is out of sync with the file system" error, which is progress.  Thank you.

Comment: Seems to work.  Even though I initially copied the ant generated jar to the lib, refreshed etc that did not work.  But, exporting it to the lib location did work.  Adding it as dependent Project does not work.

Answer (score 1):

As I see you re using Eclipse I strongly suggest you Wtp or maven based project...those will simplify your life

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept or upvote my answer if you think is right / useful